# Best way to have perpetually running DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that persistently monitors a filesystem and executes when new files are present. I want one copy of this dag to be running perpetually and I'm wondering the best way to accomplish this?

E.g. as soon as one dag run finishes another begins.

I could accomplish this by scheduling DAGs every few minutes, and then limiting concurrent dags to 1, but I'm guessing there is a more systematic way to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think there is a cleaner way to do it. Airflow is a batch scheduler which means that there is some gap of time between one run and another.